# Помогите перевести из jq в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $(".add").on("click", function () {
$(".personal-adress-inner").append('<div class="web-form-item control"><textarea placeholder=" " ></textarea><div class="web-form-item-control"><div class="web-form-item-undis">     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">          <path d="M12 20H21" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>          <path d="M16.5 3.50001C16.8978 3.10219 17.4374 2.87869 18 2.87869C18.2786 2.87869 18.5544 2.93356 18.8118 3.04017C19.0692 3.14677 19.303 3.30303 19.5 3.50001C19.697 3.697 19.8532 3.93085 19.9598 4.18822C20.0665 4.44559 20.1213 4.72144 20.1213 5.00001C20.1213 5.27859 20.0665 5.55444 19.9598 5.81181C19.8532 6.06918 19.697 6.30303 19.5 6.50001L7 19L3 20L4 16L16.5 3.50001Z" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>    </svg>     </div>      <div class="web-form-item-clear">        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">          <path d="M18 6L6 18M6 6L18 18" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>        </svg>      </div>    </div>  </div>');  }); })
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://properprogramming.com/tools/converters/jquery-to-javascript-remover-converter-online-alternative-version-2/

Comment: https://properprogramming.com выводит тот же код

Comment: @АлександрОрлов я вставил ваш jQuery  и вот получил:   `document.querySelector(".add").on("click", function () {
document.querySelector(".personal-adress-inner").append()`

Comment: @MonkeyMutant `.on("click"` надо заменить на `addEventListener('click'`

Comment: @SwaD я знаю...хотя я,читал что не имеет значения за некоторым исключением...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.personal-adress-inner').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<div class="web-form-item control"><textarea placeholder=" " ></textarea><div class="web-form-item-control"><div class="web-form-item-undis"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"><path d="M12 20H21" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path d="M16.5 3.50001C16.8978 3.10219 17.4374 2.87869 18 2.87869C18.2786 2.87869 18.5544 2.93356 18.8118 3.04017C19.0692 3.14677 19.303 3.30303 19.5 3.50001C19.697 3.697 19.8532 3.93085 19.9598 4.18822C20.0665 4.44559 20.1213 4.72144 20.1213 5.00001C20.1213 5.27859 20.0665 5.55444 19.9598 5.81181C19.8532 6.06918 19.697 6.30303 19.5 6.50001L7 19L3 20L4 16L16.5 3.50001Z" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div><div class="web-form-item-clear"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"><path d="M18 6L6 18M6 6L18 18" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div></div></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const personalAdressInner = document.querySelector(".personal-adress-inner");

  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("web-form-item", "control");

  const textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", " ");

  const itemControl = document.createElement("div");
  itemControl.classList.add("web-form-item-control");

  const itemUndis = document.createElement("div");
  itemUndis.classList.add("web-form-item-undis");

  const svgUndis = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  svgUndis.setAttribute("width", "24");
  svgUndis.setAttribute("height", "24");
  svgUndis.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
  svgUndis.setAttribute("fill", "none");

  const pathUndis1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  pathUndis1.setAttribute("d", "M12 20H21");
  pathUndis1.setAttribute("stroke", "#999999");
  pathUndis1.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1.5");
  pathUndis1.setAttribute("stroke-linecap", "round");
  pathUndis1.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");

  const pathUndis2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  pathUndis2.setAttribute("d", "M16.5 3.50001C16.8978 3.10219 17.4374 2.87869 18 2.87869C18.2786 2.87869 18.5544 2.93356 18.8118 3.04017C19.0692 3.14677 19.303 3.30303 19.5 3.50001C19.697 3.697 19.8532 3.93085 19.9598 4.18822C20.0665 4.44559 20.1213 4.72144 20.1213 5.00001C20.1213 5.27859 20.0665 5.55444 19.9598 5.81181C19.8532 6.06918 19.697 6.30303 19.5 6.50001L7 19L3 20L4 16L16.5 3.50001Z");
  pathUndis2.setAttribute("stroke", "#999999");
  pathUndis2.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1.5");
  pathUndis2.setAttribute("stroke-linecap", "round");
  pathUndis2.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");

  svgUndis.appendChild(pathUndis1);
  svgUndis.appendChild(pathUndis2);
  itemUndis.appendChild(svgUndis);

  const itemClear = document.createElement("div");
  itemClear.classList.add("web-form-item-clear");

  const svgClear = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  svgClear.setAttribute("width", "24");
  svgClear.setAttribute("height", "24");
  svgClear.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
  svgClear.setAttribute("fill", "none");

  const pathClear = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  pathClear.setAttribute("d", "M18 6L6 18M6 6L18 18");
  pathClear.setAttribute("stroke", "#999999");
  pathClear.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1.5");
  pathClear.setAttribute("stroke-linecap", "round");
  pathClear.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");

  svgClear.appendChild(pathClear);
  itemClear.appendChild(svgClear);

  itemControl.appendChild(itemUndis);
  itemControl.appendChild(itemClear);

  div.appendChild(textarea);
  div.appendChild(itemControl);

  personalAdressInner.appendChild(div);
});
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).